# Reinitialize reveal (Foundation 6.0.1)

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

I have few elements with class `reveal` and elements to toggle them. Thing is, some of these are added from ajax response. Naturally, these added from ajax response do not work. From some googling, I found out that you need to initialize foundation again, so I do `$(document).foundation();`. Beautiful, reveal now works for newly added elements but it behaves weirdly for old ones (you need to click twice for it to work now). So I assume, for it to work properly, I'd need to uninitialize foundation or at least reveal before initializing it again. Thing is, no matter what I try, it won't do it. So question is - how to properly uninitialize foundation or at least reveal?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but the issue can be very easily solved by reinitializing the reveal part of foundation by typing:`Foundation.reInit('accordion');`, this works for me at least. [enter link description here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#adding-content-to-plugins)